# I found this "[\\?&]v=([^&#]*)" on the internet can someone explain it to me

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, youtube

I found a method on the internet that can retrieve the Id of a youtube video from the url.

this is it.

```
var vid;
var results;
results = url.match("[\\?&]v=([^&#]*)");
vid = ( results === null ) ? url : results[1];
```

The Id will be contained in "vid".

What I don't understand and I find interesting and want to know is this.

```
results = url.match("[\\?&]v=([^&#]*)");
```

How does it work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's using a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) to extract the ID of the video from a complete URL. This particular regex breaks down as follows:

1. `[\\?&]` is a character class. It matches a single character which is either `&` or `?`. (The question mark is a special character in JavaScript regexes, so it must be escaped by preceding it with a backslash. The backslash is a special character in JavaScript strings, so *it* must be escaped also, hence the double backslash. That's fairly common in regular expressions.)
2. `v=` matches the literal string `v=`.
3. `(` begins a capturing group, so everything until the next `)` will be placed into a separate entry in the returned array.
4. `[^&#]*` any number of characters (including none) until a `&` or `#` is found. The brackets indicate a character class as above, and the `^` inverts the class so it includes all characters *except* those listed before the end bracket. The `*` indicates that the preceding character class is to be matched zero or more times.
5. The `)` ends the capturing group.

Assuming the match is successful, `results[0]` contains the entire URL, and `results[1]` contains the contents of the first capturing group, i.e. the ID of the video.

Comment: +1 for explaining step-by-step; it's the most helpful answer posted

Comment: Deleted my post. Yours is better  :-)

Comment: That wasn't necessary; there's plenty of room here for both of us. :D Still, thanks for the compliment. I'm glad people think my explanation is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This matches the video id in a youtube url.

`[\\?&]v=` // finds the first ?v= or &v= in the query string

`([^&#]*)` // matches everything else up to the next & or #

The video id is stored in `results[1]` (assuming there was a match)